# ACF Order by option within a post object field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a post type of listing.  In each listing is post object named package that is connected to another post type of package. There is then a field attached to each package named sort.  I need to be able to use the sort value to order the listings.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','alter_query');
function alter_query($query) {
    global $wp_query;

    if( $query->is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive( 'listing' ) ) {

        // Package is a post object attached to the listing post type. 
        // It allows you to select from a packages post type.
        $package = get_field('package');

        // Sort is a numeric field attached to the packages post type.
        $sort = get_field('sort',$package->post_ID);

        $query->set('orderby', array( 
          ...
        ));

        remove_all_actions ( '__after_loop');
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I’m understanding your setup here completely, but I don’t think what you have shown can work. `$package = get_field('package');` - which post id do you expect this to get the meta value from here? You are interfering at the point where the query to _get_ posts is assembled here.

Comment: I placed it in the code to give the field names and comments not to be working code. I am guessing some sort of custom query with joins is needed but I cant seem to figure it out.